# Does libxslt have a feature for splitting a document into multiple documents?

Tags: xml, xslt, libxslt

Looks like libxslt does not support XSLT 2.0, and `xsl:result-document`. Is there a way to mimic `xsl:result-document` using `libxslt`, or `xsltproc`?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is, using [exsl:document](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html). A simple example:

```
==== foo.xsl ====
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <exsl:document href="toc.html" method="html">
      <html>
        <body>
          <xsl:apply-templates select=".//h1"/>
        </body>
      </html>
    </exsl:document>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

taking this as input:

```
==== foo.html ====
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>Some longwinded text follows.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

when run like this:

```
xsltproc foo.xsl foo.html
```

will yield this to stdout:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>Some longwinded text follows.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

while also writing this to `toc.html`:

```
<html><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1></body></html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If libxslt implements **[EXSLT](http://exslt.org)**, then you could use the **[`<exsl:document>`](http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html)** extension element.

If not, then you have to write your own extension functions, because XSLT 1.0 does not support creating multiple result documents.

**Update**: As confirmed in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167912/does-libxslt-have-a-feature-for-splitting-a-document-into-multiple-documents/3168184#3168184), libxslt implements EXSLT. Just grab it and use **[`<exsl:document>`](http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html)** .

Comment: libxslt the project does; it's provided in libexslt.a.

Answer (score 2):

And here is an example that shows how to use the extension to create an unlimited number of files as a nodeset is traversed.  Again, using xsltproc (libxslt)

## Sample XML Input:

```
<clients>
    <client id="ACME1" name="ACME Company 1"/>
    <client id="ACME2" name="ACME Company 2"/>
    <client id="ACME3" name="ACME Company 3"/>
</clients>
```

## Sample XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/clients/client">
    <exsl:document href="{@id}.html" method="html">
      <html>
        <body>
          <h1>Company: <xsl:apply-templates select="@name"/></h1>
        </body>
      </html>
    </exsl:document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will produce 3 files ACME1.html, ACME2.html, etc.