# How to transform single input XML file into two separate XML documents using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a single XML document and want to transform into two separate XML documents using single XSLT file based on an occurrence of a particular XML tag in XML file.

For example,

A.xml ----> has a Tag `<Customer convertto = "Master">` then I should convert into Master.xml file.

If A.xml file has a `<Customer convertto = "Child">` then I should convert into Child.xml file.

In both cases I want to use single XSLT file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does libxslt have a feature for splitting a document into multiple documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167912/does-libxslt-have-a-feature-for-splitting-a-document-into-multiple-documents)

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 use the `<xsl:result-document>` instruction.